# Изменение шрифта текста в TabLayout и TabItem

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

Всем привет. Как можно сменить (а можно ли) шрифт текста в `TabLayout` и `TabItem` в Android приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Сменить шрифт у табов можно так:

```
public static void changeTabsFont(Context context, TabLayout tabLayout, int color) {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "YoursAwersomeFont.ttf"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```